# Canvas not rending custom font in server side image generation

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to use Canvas to generate images via an API because I need to programmatically generate images using a background image and overlaying custom text.

I am writing the server in Node JS.

Current implementation in "pages/api/image.js":

```
import "@fontsource/press-start-2p"; //Font I am trying to use -- successfully loads in React web UI
const { createCanvas, loadImage } = require("canvas");

export async function generateImage(body) {
      const canvas = createCanvas(width, height);
      const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
...
      context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height); //draws background image - no problem
...
      context.font = "16pt Press Start 2P";          //Font defaults to other alternative
      context.fillText("Sample text", 40, 40);
```

I cannot figure out if Canvas cannot support the custom font, or if I am loading the font incorrectly.

Does anyone have any tips on how to generate these images with the custom font?  I am open to a non Canvas solution if that is a limitation of the package.

Comment: You need to [`Canvas.registerFont()`](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas#registerfont) before creating the canvas.

Comment: 100%  - Thanks @Kaiido that worked beautifully and it ends my 10+ hour struggle on the edge of madness trying to figure this out.